# Azure - 92036-Microsoft .NET Security Update for July 2023

Tags: azure

In Azure, under Microsoft Defender for Cloud, I'm getting the following issue: 92036-Microsoft .NET Security Update for July 2023.  How do I fix this?  Are there patches I need to install, or do I just wait for the fix to appear in Windows Updates (I don't see anything in there now), and install from there?